# java.lang.ClassCastException: Creating a synchronized Linked List

Tags: java, generics, linked-list, synchronized, classcastexception

I want a synchronized LinkedList with a Generic Class A, here the relevant parts:

```
public abstract class A<T extends B> implements Runnable {
```

And the interface for B, where the "real" B, will be a supclass

```
public interface B{
```

Following setup will throw a runtime error:

```
LinkedList<A<? extends B>> eopList = (LinkedList<A<? extends B>>) Collections
            .synchronizedCollection(new LinkedList<A<? extends B>>());
```

I've found the following proposal, but it also won't compile:

```
LinkedList<A<? extends B>> eopList = (LinkedList) Collections
            .synchronizedCollection(new LinkedList<A<? extends B>>());
```

This Is the Log:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection cannot be cast to java.util.LinkedList
```

Comment: Try Collection<A<? extends B>> eopList = Collections
            .synchronizedCollection(new LinkedList<A<? extends B>>());

Comment: These are not compile errors. They are run-time exceptions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`Collections.synchronizedList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29) method instead. The method returns a `List<T>`. So, make the type on LHS as `List`, to avoid typecast:

```
List<A<? extends B>> eopList = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<A<? extends B>>());
```

Answer (score 1):

In the words of [nos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/126769/nos) on [Is LinkedList thread-safe when I'm accessing it with offer and poll exclusively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362018/is-linkedlist-thread-safe-when-im-accessing-it-with-offer-and-poll-exclusively/3362063#3362063):

> LinkedList is not thread safe. You'll have to do the locking yourself.
>
> Try [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) or [LinkedBlockingDeque](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingDeque.html) instead if
>   it fits your needs

or try this code from [Piyush Hari](https://stackoverflow.com/users/585512/piyush-hari)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362018/is-linkedlist-thread-safe-when-im-accessing-it-with-offer-and-poll-exclusively/17981472#17981472):

```
  LinkedList<A<? extends B>> eopList = (LinkedList)Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<A<? extends B>());
```

Comment: -1 This simply repeats the same mistake made by the OP - the `List` returned by `synchronizedList` wraps the `LinkedList` but is not itself a `LinkedList`.