# how can I have a linked list that multiple clients can read write to?

Tags: java, multithreading, client, server

I have a multithreaded server and can have multiple clients at once connected. These threads call a class that has multiple linked lists and the clients can add and remove information to it.
For example
This is the server

```
public class ShareServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    //if (args.length != 1) {
        //System.err.println("Usage: java ShareServer <port number>");
        //System.exit(1);
    //}

       //int portNumber = 2000;
        boolean listening = true;

        try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(2000)) { 
            while (listening) {
                new ClientThread(serverSocket.accept()).start();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not listen on port " + 2000);
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the clientsthread

```
public class ClientThread extends Thread {
private Socket socket = null;
private ObjectOutputStream out;
private ObjectInputStream in;
FindMatch look= new FindMatch();
string fruit;

public ClientThread(Socket socket) {
    super("ClientThread");
    this.socket = socket;
}

public void run() {

    try {
        out = new ObjectOutputStream (socket.getOutputStream());
        in = new ObjectInputStream (socket.getInputStream());

        int count=0;
            boolean flag = false;

                try{

                    fruit = (Double)in.readObject();

                        flag = look.checkForMatch(string fruit);
                        if(flag==true)
                            sendMessage("found a match")


                }


                catch(ClassNotFoundException classnot){
                    System.err.println("Data received in unknown format");
                }

        socket.close();
    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

void sendMessage(string fuit)
{
    try{
        out.writeObject(msg);
        out.flush();
        System.out.println("server>" + msg);
    }
    catch(IOException ioException){
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}



   public LinkedList<String> fruitEntries = new LinkedList<Integer>();
public LinkedList<?> clientID = new LinkedList <?>();
```

this is the code that it calls

```
boolean checkFormatch(string fruit){   
for(int i = 0; i< fruitEntries.length();i++){
        if(fruit == fruitEntries.get(i)){
            tell client at clientID(i);
            fruitEntries.remove(i);
            clientID.remove(i);
            retutn true;
        }
}
}
```

This code is far from perfect I just threw this together. the general idea is right though. I will have maybe 6 linked lists of info in mine.
I'm not sure how to keep track of what thread a client has either so I would appreciate help with that.

Comment: Why a linked list? Isn't a `CopyOnWriteArrayList` enough?

Comment: @fge The list would be modified with every client connection. I read somewhere that CopyOnWriteArrayList shouldnt be used if this is the case? also its expensive to use and if i have hundreds of clients it may not be the best option.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19510360/java-lang-classcastexception-creating-a-synchronized-linked-list

Comment: @McT the general idea is not quite right. naive search. manual re-implementation of List.indexOf(). lack of synchronisation on a set of mutating collections.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use RMI instead of sockets. RMI handles all the messy listening threading etc.

Consider using one of the java.util.concurrent classes -- ConcurrentSkipListMap
ConcurrentHashMap

Also, when you compare Strings you need fruit.compareTo(...) which is rather slow so creating a hash is probably better.