# Is using static LinkedList on server side safe?

Tags: java, servlets, linked-list

I am giving users the option to edit the files in my db. But i dont want multiple edits to the same file at the same time and therefore to prevent this i have used a static linked list on my server side. When the client will send the request to update file to server , LinkedList.contain(filename) will check if the file name exists in the list or not. If it doesn't exist then it will add it and allow update, else it will just return the response as an error occurred.. The code is something like this:

```
public class UpdateFileServlet extends HttpServlet{

    private static List<String> List= new LinkedList<String>();
        @Override
        public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
                    throws ServletException, IOException {
            String file=req.getHeader("FileName");
            if(List.contains(file)){
                res.getWriter().write("Error");
                res.flushBuffer();
                return;
            }
            List.add(file);
            try{
            //do the file update;

                List.remove(file);

            }catch (Exception e1) {
                List.remove(file);
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have also added try/catch, so that even if any exception occurs then also the name of the file will be removed from the list. Otherwise the file will become non editable forever. I know this isn't the best method, but i want to know if there is any condition in which the linkedlist will fail Or is there any better solution to the problem???

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestion...

Comment: `LinkedList` by itself isn't thread safe (not synchronized). You might want to have a look at questions like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362018/is-linkedlist-thread-safe-when-im-accessing-it-with-offer-and-poll-exclusively) one to make sure you're ok. Servlets *should* be stateless, so you could think about using a database instead.

Comment: Just a note: Variables should start with a lower case character ;)

Comment: It is not safe, imagine case you have two users who are working at the same time with your system, and both want to access same file simultaneously.
they both passed check `if(List.contains(file))` before you added file to list.

Comment: Avoid static and instance members in Servlet. If used then be careful about multi threading issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several points.

1. `LinkedList` isn't thread safe. Also searching time is linear. You might want to consider `ConcurrentHashMap`. Instead of doing `list.add()` you do `ConcurrentMap.putIfAbsent()` and check the returned value.
2. People might pass in different path e.g. absolute vs relative path all pointing to the same actual file. So it's better to use `File` object instead of string in your holding structure.
3. I guess you want to do `list.remove(file)` regardless if the update is successful. So you need to put it to the `finally` block.

Comment: thanks for the answer...jst one think...r u sure that ConcurrentMap.putIfAbsent() wont take two request if they come at the same time??

Comment: It's possible for ConcurrentMap.putIfAbsent() to receive 2 requests together; but the implementations, e.g. ConcurrentHashMap, has its internal locks. In the case of ConcurrentHashMap, it has a ReadWriteLock on each "cell" in the internal hash table. By doing so it achieves better performance than using a synchronized or ReadWriteLock on the entire map structure. So even if you have 2 calls together, only 1 of the calls would return true.

Comment: No prob. Enjoy coding :-)