# Is it safe to add items to a linked list while iterating

Tags: java, linked-list, iterator, listiterator

Is it safe to add items to a `LinkedList` while iterating?

```
class Worker {

    final LinkedList<Foo> worklist = new LinkedList<>();

    public void work() {

        Iterator<Foo> iterator = worklist.iterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {

            Foo foo = iterator.next();

            doSomethingWith(foo);
        }
    }

    public void doSomethingWith(Foo foo) {

        // do something with foo            

        // and possibly add one (or more) foo's to the worklist
        if (expression) {
            worklist.add(new Foo());
        }
    }
}
```

If not, how can this behaviour be implemented in a safe and efficient way?

Note that this is not [about a `List`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26888845/is-it-safe-to-add-items-to-the-list-while-iterating-through-it), but specifically about a `LinkedList`. If it isn't safe, I'm asking about alternatives.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362018/is-linkedlist-thread-safe-when-im-accessing-it-with-offer-and-poll-exclusively  Being able to change values within a list while iterating is also a property associated with multithreading. General rule if a list can use a iterator it isn't thread safe

Comment: If you change the list while iterating over it, it will throw ConcurrentModificationException.

Comment: Why not to use ListIterator and add element with help of iterator? We can access it with worklist.listIterator()

Comment: @IvanBochko I have to iterate over the added elements too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: adding elements to a collection during iteration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/993025/java-adding-elements-to-a-collection-during-iteration)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, it is not safe. The following code will throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`:

```
final LinkedList<Foo> worklist = new LinkedList<>();
worklist.add(new Foo());
Iterator<Foo> iterator = worklist.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Foo foo = iterator.next();
    worklist.add(new Foo());
}
```

[`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) does not override [`iterator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#iterator--) and the default implementation, defined in [`AbstractSequentialList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractSequentialList.html) is to call `listIterator()`, and `LinkedList` does override [`listIterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#listIterator-int-).

Quoting the documentation of `LinkedList.listIterator`:

> The list-iterator is *fail-fast*: if the list is structurally modified at any time after the Iterator is created, in any way except through the list-iterator's own `remove` or `add` methods, the list-iterator will throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

What you want is to use explicitely a [`ListIterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html), instead of an `Iterator`, and use [`ListIterator.add`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#add-E-):

```
final LinkedList<Foo> worklist = new LinkedList<>();
worklist.add(new Foo());
ListIterator<Foo> iterator = worklist.listIterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Foo foo = iterator.next();
    iterator.add(new Foo());
}
```

The new element is inserted before the element that was returned by `next()` so subsequent calls to `next()` are unaffected. If you want to add the new item to the iteration, you can call `previous()` (and ignore the return value) after adding the element to move the cursor backwards.

Comment: But I have to iterate over the added element too. I've edited the code example in the question.

Comment: @Tim see my edit, you can call `previous()` to add the element to the current iteration.